# How to trigger Jenkins Builds from Github Pull Requests

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Using an organization type project in jenkins, I expected the pull requests to get automatically built.

I have a github webhook created in github settings. but nothing seems to be done?

Is there anything i need to put in my jenkinsfile to make this happen

Comment: There are several ways how to get this work, all of them are dependent of you actual setup.

Comment: @rkosegi I am just using a Jenkinsfile and using the organisation type project.

Comment: @rkosegi  I am just using a Jenkinsfile and using the organisation type project. Don't understand what other setup matters

Comment: What do you see in https://JENKINS_URL/jenkins/job/JOB_NAME/indexing/console ?

Comment: I have it possible to index and run every minute and check for updates to PR's but rather i would like for github to basically send a webhook request everytime a PR is updated and that triggers the build